# Custom view(xib) to specific controller in the storyboard

Tags: ios

I have a custom view (xib) that pop up in several locations in my project..

when i clicked on specified button on my custom view , i need to open speciec viewController  in the story board , i try this but nothing happaned :

AWSS3TransferManager *transferManager = [AWSS3TransferManager defaultS3TransferManager];

Please advice !

Comment: sorry this code is :

Comment: UIStoryboard*  sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                  bundle:nil];
    self.mapController = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mapCon"];
    [self.window addSubview:self.mapController];